# Why do I get this output? (Python)

Tags: python, file

`numbers.txt` has 2 lines: 123 and 456

When I run this:

```
list = open('numbers.txt').read().splitlines()
print list
```

It gives me this output:

> ['{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\cocoartf1404\cocoasubrtf340', '{\fonttbl\f0\fswiss\fcharset0 ArialMT;}', '{\colortbl;\red255\green255\blue255;}', '\paperw11900\paperh16840\margl1440\margr1440\vieww8860\viewh6060\viewkind0', '\deftab720', '\pard\pardeftab720\sl480\sa144\partightenfactor0', '', '\f0\fs32 \cf0 \expnd0\expndtw0\kerning0', '123\', '456}']

Comment: Are you sure your file actually contains only those lines, or does it actually contain other values that are hidden by MS Word, WordPad, Pages, or whatever you edited it with? Try opening it up with notepad.

Comment: It's not a `txt` file at all. (`pdf`, `Word`?).

Comment: Im betting on wordpad ...

Comment: Yes, it was TextEdit on iOS... never using it again. Thanks guys!

Comment: Just make sure when you save you save as plain text instead of some other format and it should work in the future.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this is an rtf file. This appears to be the first line which has a lot of formatting of text, font size, etc. You can delete the first line with the following:

```
del list[0]
```

Otherwise you could just select the lines you want by referencing their index.